# If Shri Shani Dev is "karma" phal daata, why he troubled the godly & righteous avatars of Vishnu? What bad karma did they have?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, shani

We all know that Shri Shani Dev is Karma phala daata..

But while reading shani-mahatmya (its a marathi book)

Shri Shani Dev tells to King Vikram that due to him Lord Rama suffered VanVaas.
Due to him Lord Krishna suffered a blame. Lord Shiva also suffered due to him.

While its understandable that Ravan was killed due to his bad karma of kidnapping Sita mata but what bad karma did Lord Rama, Lord Krishna, Lord Shiva carried to be punished by Shri Shani Deva ?